# TCPDF Barcode 128 subset switch

Tags: php, pdf, barcode, tcpdf, code128

I'm using TCPDF to generate a Code-128 barcode, but I need to be able to switch the subset from B to C.

I have tried using TCPDF 'C128' which changes the subset automatically but not to the correct position that I need it for.

I am also aware that you could and certain values called control switches which can change the subset like ZPL command '>5' which changes the subset of a code-128 barcode to subset C. But have yet to find an away to change to do this for TCPDF.

There are two different versions of the barcode I need, each barcode changes their subset from B to C in different positions

Barcode

%0075009159766332625033252250

1st version of Subset of Barcode

BBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

2nd version of Subset of Barcode

BBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

Any help would be greatly appreciated.